MYSQL - variable sum(case + WHERE IS NOT NULL
I am using the below mysql SELECT query which works fine but I am missing 2 things.
SELECT month(fac_factures.periode_date) as date,
SUM(CASE WHEN fac_articles.famille = '3' THEN totalht END) as 'management',
SUM(CASE WHEN fac_articles.famille = '5' THEN totalht END) as 'conseil',
SUM(CASE WHEN fac_articles.famille = '6' THEN totalht END) as 'audit',
SUM(CASE WHEN fac_articles.famille = '7' THEN totalht END) as 'formation',
SUM(CASE WHEN fac_articles.famille = '4' THEN totalht END) as 'refac'
from fac_facturearticles
LEFT JOIN fac_factures ON fac_facturearticles.facture = fac_factures.facture_id
LEFT JOIN fac_clients ON fac_factures.facture_client = fac_clients.client_id
LEFT JOIN fac_articles ON fac_facturearticles.article = fac_articles.article_id
LEFT JOIN fac_articles_familles ON fac_articles.famille = fac_articles_familles.articlefamille_id
LEFT JOIN fac_articles_natures ON fac_articles.nature = fac_articles_natures.articlenature_id
WHERE totalht is not NULL
group by year(fac_factures.periode_date), month(fac_factures.periode_date)
order by year(fac_factures.periode_date), month(fac_factures.periode_date);


The problem with the "SUM(CASE WHEN" clause is that I need to state each and every existing and to come fac_articles.famille.

Is there a way to trick the code so the number of columns is automatically adjusted based on the number of fac?_articles.famille
| date    | fac_articles.famille1 | fac_articles.famille2 | fac_articles.famille... |
| ------- | --------------------- | --------------------- | ----------------------- |
| date1   | totalht               | totalht               | totalht                 |
| date2   | totalht               | totalht               | totalht                 |
| date... | totalht               | totalht               | totalht                 |


then, I would like to display a column for fac_articles.famille only when totalht is not NULL.
I am not sure if the current WHERE clause is appropriate.

Thanks a lot for your help.

In a SQL query, all columns in the select-list must be fixed before it begins reading data. So it cannot automatically append more columns to the result depending on the data values read during execution.
What you're asking is like trying to code a Java function whose arguments depend on the return value of the same function call. You can't get the return value before you call the function, but you can't call the function without knowing the arguments. It's a circular dependency, which cannot be solved.
This also is related to your second question. The number of columns of the result is fixed. You can't make some columns not appear in the result set depending on values in the result.
